# Idris interactive prover won't perform rewrite on an assumption

Tags: proof, idris

(I know the interactive prover is deprecated now in favour of elaborator reflection, but I've not got around to updating yet. Soon!)

I have the following assumptions currently available in the prover (among others):

```
x : Nat
c : Nat
m : Nat
lte : LTE c m
pma : x + (m - c) = (x + m) - c
p : Part (S c) (plus x (minus m c))
```

`pma` was created using a function I wrote myself which, given natural numbers *x*, *y*, *z* and a proof that *z ≤ y*, produces a proof that *x + (y - z) = (x + y) - z*.

`Part n x` is the type of partitions of the natural number `x` into `n` pieces (each piece being a natural number), where order matters.

What I'd like to do is rewrite the type of `p` using `pma` to produce a new assumption:

```
p' : Part (S c) (minus (plus x m) c)
```

However, I tried:

```
let p' = rewrite pma in p
```

and also:

```
let p' = rewrite (sym pma) in p
```

because I can never remember which way round `rewrite` works, and in both cases I got:

```
rewrite did not change type letty
```

Where am I slipping up? I thought it might be because there's some difference between `plus` and `+` and between `minus` and `-`, but I'm pretty sure I've used them interchangeably in proofs before. Is there some other difference between the expressions that I'm missing?

I'm using Idris version 0.9.18-, if that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `pma : x + (m - c) = (x + m) - c` to `rewrite` the type of something that is typed `E1 + (E2 - E3)`, for some choice of `E1`, `E2` and `E3`. However, you have

```
p : Part (S c) (plus x (minus m c))
```

which is **not** of that form. But it **is** of the form `P (E1 + (E2 - E3))`. So we need to lift your equality of

```
E1 + (E2 - E3) ~> (E1 + E2) - E3
```

to

```
P (E1 + (E2 - E3)) ~> P ((E1 + E2) - E3)
```

This is exactly what [`replace`](https://github.com/idris-lang/Idris-dev/blob/v0.9.18/libs/prelude/Builtins.idr#L71) does:

```
replace : {a:_} -> {x:_} -> {y:_} -> {P : a -> Type} -> x = y -> P x -> P y
replace Refl prf = prf
```

So in your particular case, given

```
pma : x + (m - c) = (x + m) - c
```

then

```
replace {Part (S c)} pma : Part (S c) (x + (m - c)) -> Part (S c) ((x + m) - c)
```

and in particular,

```
replace {Part (S c)} pma p : Part (S c) ((x + m) - c)
```